# Dynamic Query Parameter from PowerBI Embedded and Create dynamic query for Database(Direct Query)

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a requirement to display a graph based on the data we fetch from the Database(Oracle) , the fetching is `Direct Query`

Now the question is

1. I know the User when a user logged into Java Web Application
2. How can I leverage that user and create a dynamic query to fetch data from the database
3. The reason is there are millions of record and user have subset of data access , so instead of fetching all the data in power BI and apply RLS , it is better to filter at the database layer
4. And I can't store data in the Cloud due to legal constraints and hence Direct Query

Please let me know , if you need more details

Comment: Use [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters) instead of parameters, and let the [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding) do its job.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov filter pass from Application , lets say user_id , we need to replace query dynamically and execute in database `select * from employee where user_id = <variable_user_id>` , can this be done??

Comment: No, your query should be `select * from employee` only. When you add a filter, Power BI will add the where clause. This is what query folding is. See the links that I gave you in my previous comment.